# Traffic Redirection of several vlan through TPROXY

Tags: iptables, routing, proxy, transparent-proxy

I have http proxy, whitch has been developed in my company. Proxy uses TPROXY. Usually, installation of this proxy requires adding some routing rules and iptables rules (as for squid):

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port $PROXPORT --on-ip $PROXIP
```

Now i need proxying traffic from different vlans. I don't understand how i can write ip rules for routing traffic after proxy to suitable output interface. For "suitable" i mean virtual tagged output interface coinciding with input interface.

```
+---------+                        +---------+
|         |                        |         |
| eth4.2  |--+                     | eth5.2  |
|  input  |  |                 +-->| output  |
+---------+  |   +----------+  |   +---------+
             |   |          |  |  
+---------+  +-->|          |--+   +---------+
|         |      | TROXY    |      |         |
| eth4.3  |----->| Magic    |----->| eth5.3  |
|  input  |      |          |      | output  |
+---------+  +-->|          |--+   +---------+
             |   |          |  |   
+---------+  |   +----------+  |   +---------+
|         |  |                 |   |         |
| eth4.4  |--+                 +-->| eth5.4  |
|  input  |                        | output  |
+---------+                        +---------+
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use POSTROUTING chains.